# Adding a reference section and an Appendix messes up my formating

Tags: graphics, bibtex

I've been writing this report in which I need to display several regression tables in the body of the report, then add a reference part with my bibliography and finally an appendix part with several graphs. Here's what I did:

```
\section*{Results}


[...]

\input{Tables/Table2}

[...]


\pagebreak


\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{Microeconometrics.bib}


\pagebreak


\section*{Appendix}


\begin{figure}

   \centering

   \includegraphics{Images/CognitionDistrib.jpg}

   \caption{Cognition Scores}

\end{figure}


\begin{figure}

   \centering

   \includegraphics{Images/MentalDistrib.jpg}

   \caption{Distribution of mental health score}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This causes all sorts of issues. Firstly, my table 2 is not where it's supposed to be: it appears after the body of text just before the reference part. There is no page break between the table 2 and the references. Then the first figure that I use appears before the Appendix section.

I suspect this is due to the size of the tables and images but I'm not sure and I wouldn't know how to fix this.

Thanks for the help !

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried `\clearpage` instead `\pagebreak`?

Answer (score 0):

So I've fixed my issue with graphs misplacement using [h!], but the issue of my table 2 being misplaced still remains, here's my code:

```
[...]

\input{Tables/Table2}

[...]

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Microeconometrics.bib}

\newpage

\section*{Appendix}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Images/CognitionDistrib.jpg}
    \caption{Distribution of cognition score}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Images/MentalDistrib.jpg}
    \caption{Distribution of mental health index}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

When I do this, the table appears between the \newpage and the bibliography. I tried both \newpage and \pagebreak but there doesn't seem to be a difference. I might be wrong on that though.

Any help appreciated !

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete this and edit your original question. You do not show the code for your "misplaced" table. I assume that it is too large to fit where you called for it so it got moved to the next page.